# Enum with instance method as values

Tags: python, oop, enums

For example I have a class to define some operations that can be done:

```py
class MathOps:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    def add(self):
        return self.a + self.b
    def subtract(self):
        return self.a - self.b
```

Somewhere in the codebase, this `MathOps` object is instantiated.

```py
operation1 = MathOps(10, 5)
```

Is it possible to use Enum to map which math operation the user wants to do?

```py
class SelectOps(enum.Enum):
    ADDITION = ... # please do operation1.add()
    SUBTRACTION = ... # please do operation1.subtract()
```

For example if the user defines he wants to do "ADDITION" (this is defined in a separate config file), I want to do something like this:

```py
results = SelectOps['ADDITION'].value
```

and if the user wants to do "SUBTRACTION",

```py
results = SelectOps['SUBTRACTION'].value
```

Can I do that?

Comment: Just use a dict, it's easier

Comment: How can I define the dictionary that has object operation1.add() as the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `dict` and store the method itself, then call them on the appropriate `MathOps` instance

```
operators = {
    "ADDITION": MathOps.add,
    "SUBTRACTION": MathOps.subtract,
}

v1, v2, choice = 10, 5, "ADDITION"

operation1 = MathOps(v1, v2)
method_to_call = operators[choice]
result = method_to_call(operation1)

print(result)  # 15
```